# Django: Get base URL for sending links in email

Tags: python, django, django-commands

I have a django app `myapp`, which registers a menu-command `foo` to be called via `./manage.py foo`.

The command should send a reminder email to all users. The mail contains a link in it, to a specific view, lets say `bar`. `bar` has the this entry in the `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.bar, name='bar'),
```

How do I correctly determine the absolute url in this context?

The relative url would be `reverse('myapp:bar')`. But how do I get the base to that?

I could just hardcode it in `settings.py` of my project, but that would go against the philosophy of django, wouldn't it?

Comment: reverse("myapp:name_of_the_url")

Comment: @VictorCastilloTorres You're right. I corrected the question.